# Alternatives to put in a feeding toy other than food

Tags: cats, feeding, toys

I recently bought a feeding toy (something like [this](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0652/8253/9769/products/12_b9a05064-76d1-4f52-855c-4c1248241c12.png?v=1662347037)) for my cat and he absolutely LOVES it. But I can't put food in the toy all the time because I don't want him to become obese. It breaks my heart to see him sitting next to the empty toy, wanting to play and eat. Are there any alternatives that I can put in the toy to keep him entertained and healthy at the same time? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe remove the toy entirely? You do not fill your plates with something after you eat, just to have them full...

Comment: If not in use, I would guess to store the toy in a cupboard or another place, that cat can not see/reach it.

Comment: I've thought about putting away the toy too, but this toy is one of the few toys that he likes, and if I do that he'd go back to sleeping most of the day. I was happy that I finally found another toy that grabs his interest, and I'm just trying to keep him entertained for a little longer :'(

Comment: Maybe put new and strange objects in the toy (preferably ones that make noise)? An example could be like colorful crumply paper. Cats are very curious and to satisfy his curiosity he might be motivated to pull the strange object out so he can sniff it. The only downside is that small objects can also be a choking hazard, so you got to be careful about that...

Comment: @ Feencyx I'll consider that, thanks!

Comment: @ec08b914: cats are the kind of animal that sleeps a lot "by design". You do not need to invent tricks to keep them awake - that is (relatively) unnatural.

Answer (score 4):

If your cat loves to play with the puzzle feeder, you might want to consider switching your feeding regime to primarily involve puzzle feeders.

There are models that work for wet food too, and with kibble you can look for brands that have high quality ingredients and low caloric density.

Consider this, out in the wild cats always have to work for their food, so reducing regular meals you feed from a bowl to a minimum, or even work completely without them, is not an act of cruelty but rather the natural order of things as far as the cat is concerned.

This can actually be beneficial for their weight, given with the same total amount of food they will need to expend more calories to retrieve it compared to a bowl.

Since your cat seems to enjoy the feeder already, I don't see the harm in working with this.

---

You might even get multiple feeders to spread around the house and randomly put a small amount of kibble in a specific one, maybe while the cat is sleeping or otherwise occupied.

Cats have strong hunting instincts, and in the wild a big part of the hunt is patrolling known hideouts of prey animals, and multiple feeders with a random chance for success could somewhat simulate this and satisfy deeply rooted instincts.